# DialogInput inside ButtonBar freezes Mathematica

Tags: version-8

In Mathematica 8, if I press a button on a `ButtonBar` which contains a `DialogInput` Mathematica freezes.  Is this reproducible and is there a workaround?

```
ButtonBar[{
  "text" :> (
    DialogInput[DialogNotebook[{
        Button["Proceed", DialogReturn["return"]]
        }]];
    )}]
```

Comment: Freezed for me until I got "Abort dynamic evaluation" dialog, after which kernel crashed. v8.0.4 linux

Comment: Similarly to question above you can give the option `Method->"Queued"` to `ButtonBar`